# StaleElementReferenceException Only on FireFox and Safari

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on all link on footer of [this page](https://fueled.com/) .
Steps I followed:

1. Scroll down the page to have footer in viewport of homepage
2. Get all link elements in the footer using findElements and assign it to a list
3. For each element in list click on link, get the url of next page and compare if the URL contains few letters of the linkText I clicked on first page
4. Navigate back on home page and repeat the process for other links

I used two methods, Scroll (to scroll the page to the footer where all links are given) and Waits(to click on each link in the footer)

Problem: I am getting StaleElementReferenceException after the first link is clicked on the footer and when the page navigates back to homepage showing other elements are Stale on the page.

The code works fine on Chrome though but gives error on Firefox and Safari

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Assignment9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ChromeOptions co= new ChromeOptions();
        co.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
//      WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(co);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(40));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

        driver.get("https://fueled.com/en-gb");


        WebElement footer= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='app']/child::div[last()]"));


        List<WebElement> li= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//footer//ul[1]/li/a"));


        for(WebElement ele: li){

            try {
                waits(driver, ele, Duration.ofSeconds(80));
            }catch (TimeoutException e){
                waits(driver, ele, Duration.ofSeconds(80));
            }
            String linkText= ele.getText();

            String linkText1=linkText.substring(0, 3).toLowerCase();
//            waits(driver, ele, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
            ele.click();
            String pageUrl=driver.getCurrentUrl();
            System.out.println(pageUrl);
            if(pageUrl.contains(linkText1)){
                System.out.println(linkText + " is navigating to correct page");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Not a correct page");
            }
            driver.navigate().back();
            System.out.println("back to home page");
            scroll(driver, footer, Duration.ofSeconds(40));
            System.out.println("page has scrolled down");

        }

    }

    static void scroll(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, Duration timeout) {


        WebElement element1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='app']/child::div[last()]"));
        new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='app']/child::div[last()]")));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element1);


    }

    static void waits(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, Duration timeout) throws TimeoutException {
        WebElement footer= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='app']/child::div[last()]"));
        scroll(driver, footer, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    }
}
```

I added explicit waits in both the methods (Scroll and Waits) to wait for the element to be visible for scrolling and then click on links

I was expecting the code to work with all links without giving any error

Comment: your "li" webelement array will become stale once you click.  (either the DOM is updated via javascript or the link/page loads.)  Take each link one at a time.  (if they are standard links you can just grab the href attributes in your for loop.)  The scroll probably isn't necessary, btw, as the driver's click() method will automatically scroll the element into view.  (the exception would be if the DOM updates on scroll or if some other element is overlaying it, intercepting the click)

Comment: After clicking on the link I again navigate back to home page using navigate.back() and wait for link element to be clickable again using explicit wait. The funny thing is it works on chrome and end up giving exceptions on safari and firefox

Comment: you're not really getting an array of webelements, but snapshots/references to them? (when a method is used it will again go to the DOM to get them)  They will go stale if the DOM updates.  No idea why this works in Chrome.... I guess it's caching the references (each is given a sort of unique id) along with the page.

Comment: Thank you @pcalkins, I was able to make the code work using your suggested approach!!